# How to select data from another table if it does not exist on the other table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, where-clause

I have 3 tables, `tbl_no2016trans`, `tbl_2016_remit`, and  `tbl_2015_remit`.

`tbl_no2016trans`

```
|PEN|EMPLOYER|
| 1 | COMP_A |
| 2 | COMP_B |
| 3 | COMP_C |
| 4 | COMP_D |
| 5 | COMP_E |
```

`tbl_2016_remit`

```
|PEN|EMPLOYER|2016REMIT|
| 1 | COMP_A |  1000   |
| 2 | COMP_B |  1500   |
| 5 | COMP_E |  2500   |
```

`tbl_2015_remit`

```
|PEN|EMPLOYER|2016REMIT|
| 3 | COMP_C |  1000   |
| 4 | COMP_D |   500   |
```

need to select all columns from `tbl_2015_remit` OR `tbl_2016_remit`where the PEN in `tbl_no2016trans` exists.

I used  this code

`SELECT * FROM tbl_2015_remit WHERE PEN IN (SELECT PEN FROM tbl_no2016trans)`... but I don't know how to put the condition where select * from `tbl_2016_remit` if it doesn't exist in `tbl_2015_remit` .

I also used LEFT JOIN but still at lost.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    tbl_2015_remit
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_2016_remit
ON tbl_2015_remit.pen = tbl_201c_remit.pen
WHERE
   PEN IN (SELECT PEN from tbl_no2016trans)
```

Comment: is tbl_c has any foriegn key

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @ArunKumaresh.  nope, they all have primary key which is PEN.  it can only be present on either of the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try Union all?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_2015_remit WHERE PEN IN (SELECT PEN FROM tbl_no2016trans)
union all
SELECT * FROM tbl_2016_remit WHERE PEN IN (SELECT PEN FROM tbl_no2016trans)
```

Comment: I'm such a noob at this. thank you so much. that was really helpful.